# Select statement subquery, multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a query to select a certain condition then within that condition select two other conditions.

Breaking it down.

- `SELECT` condition 1 `FROM` column 2, if this condition is not met return nothing.
- `SELECT` condition 2 `FROM` column 3, `SELECT` condition 3 `FROM` column 4, if either of these two conditions are met return the respective column value from that rows value.

My feeble attempt which gives an obvious syntax error,

```
SELECT Column_1 
  FROM Data_TBL 
    WHERE Column_2 = 'Condition_1' 
      GROUP BY(WHERE Column_3 = 'Condition_2' OR Column_4 = 'Condition_3') 
        ORDER BY Column_1 ASC
```

Still very new to SQL statements and I am struggling with the syntax.

Comment: Show us sample data and the actual conditions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Gordon Linoff answered the question ,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a `where` clause.  For the filtering:

```
select t.*
from data_tbl t
where (column2 = 'Condition_1') and
      (column3 = 'Condition_2' or column4 = 'Condition_3);
```

I'm not sure what you want to return when both `column3` and `column4` meet the respective conditions, but I think this is what you want:

```
select (case when column3 = 'Condition_2' then column3 else column4 end)
from data_tbl t
where (column2 = 'Condition_1') and
      (column3 = 'Condition_2' or column4 = 'Condition_3);
```

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. Regards